# Go, in struct how to reference current object (like this in java and c++)?

Tags: class, go, this

What is go's `this` (or `self` in python) construct?

```
type Shape struct {
    isAlive bool
}

func (shape *Shape) setAlive(isAlive bool) {

}
```

in the `setAlive` function how do I do `this.isAlive = isAlive;` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example, `shape` is the receiver. You could even write it like this:

```
func (this *Shape) setAlive(isAlive bool) {
    this.isAlive = isAlive
}
```

Comment: s/current object/receiver/

Comment: You *could*; but [please don't](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#receiver-names). "this", "self", etc were always bad ideas/names so please only use them when you're stuck with a language that forces you to.

Answer (score 6):

Go's method declarations have a so called receiver in front of the method name.
In your example it's `(shape *Shape)`.
When you call `foo.setAlive(false)` `foo` is passed as `shape` to `setAlive`.

So basically the following is syntactical sugar

```
func (shape *Shape) setAlive(isAlive bool) {
    shape.isAlive = isAlive
}

foo.setAlive(false)
```

for

```
func setAlive(shape *Shape, isAlive bool) {
    shape.isAlive = isAlive
}

setAlive(foo, false)
```

Comment: `foo` _is not_ passed "as `shape`" to `setAlive`, but a _pointer_ to `foo` is.

Comment: I am referring to the name of the receiver, not the type.

Comment: @jnml: that is true assuming `foo` is `Shape`. but `foo` could be `*Shape`